# Local Grid Coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Does anyone know if you can create a non-earth local grid in QGIS. Local grids were commonly created in the past and are plane grids with eastings and northings from a specific reference point. QGIS only appear to be able to use real world coordinates with known projections. MapInfo has a non-earth feature that allows you to import local grid data and display it without it being in a known projection. This is particularly important when entering old data which was not referenced to real world coordinates.

Comment: If you are not interested in referencing to the real world, you can assign almost every projected CRS just to display the data.

Comment: Where do I do that in QGIS?

Comment: Rightclick on the Layer -> `Set CRS for Layer`.